# How should a fail-fast iterator fail in C

Tags: c, design-patterns, iterator

I want to implement a fail-fast iterator in C, i.e. it should fail if the list
is modified while iterating.

Location of failures will certainly be in the hasNext and next methods where I will check against the number of modifications since iterator was created. So I think I know when it should fail but I don't see how it should fail.

I thought about assert() but it's only for debug so is it ok ? And how to unit test it?
My biggest concern is to find a way to unit test this functionality.

```
// List Methods
List* List_new(void);
void List_delete(List** self);
int List_add(List* self, void* data);
size_t List_size(List* self);
void* List_head(List* self);
int List_removeHead(List* self);
ListIterator* iterator(List* self);

// ListIterator Methods
bool ListIterator_hasNext(ListIterator* self);
void* ListIterator_next(ListIterator* self);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want the program to do (or be able to do) in this instance.

Assert is probably bad, as it will kill the program, which I doubt is appropriate.

You could move most of the return values into output arguments, then return a bool indicating whether the operation was valid, which you could then assert on in your unit tests.

Comment: Great! I will try this and put a lot of "const" everywhere to make it clear what is input and what is output.